# Javascript: how to understand this weird assignment?

Tags: javascript

I found this expression on one web site.

```
var _g = _g || [];
```

What doest it mean?

Comment: Seriously, this question came up at least 4 times last week.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it simply prevent the _g value to be null or undefined, if the _g on the right side is null or undefined, _g will be assigned to an empty array.

it is like :

```
if(!_g) {
  _g = [];
}
```

Comment: Not just `null` or `undefined` but also others like `0`, `NaN`, empty string. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy

Comment: Yes sure but in this case the value expected is an array so there is few chances for having a 0 or NaN but you are right

Comment: @MathieuBertin Then if the expected value is an array, why use this guard?

Comment: because your array can not be set so undefined... You are right on the case that if _g equals NaN or 0 _g will be assigned to an empty array but I think that the developer wanted to prevent the undefined or null case that's why I didn't mention it.

Answer (score 3):

set _g equal to _g,  but if _g is undefined, set it to an empty array;